# Can I deploy the same app in multiple containers in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, docker, containers, windows-server-2016

I am consolidating a bunch of super old servers (~200).  All the code has been tweaked to be able to run on a single box.  Except there is a 3rd party web service app that listens on a socket on each one of these servers.  The vendor is not going to change the app to be able to work on a single server.

So I've read about the upcoming Containers in Windows Server 2016, though I still do not fully comprehend them.

I was wondering whether I can deploy 200 instances of a container, each running this web service inside the container.  The app itself is very easy on resources. Would this be a good case for containerization?

Comment: Maybe? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I haven't tried it.  I am just wondering whether it's a valid approach before I spend a bunch of time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can create a huge number of containers based on the same container image, a web server farm springs to mind when you need to rapidly scale up and down.

As Jim B said some things will be better off in VM's, some in nano server versions and some will be better off in Hyper V containers if you need isolation.

The great thing is that you now have the flexibility, the choice and the ability to decide what you deploy where on which platform.

Comment: Web servers would only be a container fit without any back end services, which the OP said that it has listeners.  Since containers are isolated, it would probably be better in a vm

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are doing rapid redeployments, containers are a great fit.  If its relatively static, or it requires intranet communication VMs might be a better fit.  See https://www.petri.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-windows-server-2016-containers